# Class sidebar is missing in Bootstrap 4.1 documentation with example Dashboard

Tags: bootstrap-4, dashboard, sidebar

I am not able to find the 'sidebar'-class in the bootstrap documentation although it is used in the examples: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/

Where can I find a description for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `sidebar` is defined in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css and it is not class in bootstrap.

You can see the elements in example dashboard, the `sidebar` is fixed with grid in bootstrap (`col-md-2`). Therefore, `sidebar` is not documented.

[image]

If you want to build a dashboard template, you can use free template with bootstrap at here https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-templates/. You can also search with your frameworks you are using, such as jQuery, React, Angular, Vue and so on.

Hope I've helped you!